# replacing a file in a git branch with the same file from another branch?

Tags: git

Every time I update one of my git repo and fetch a new branch or commits I want to replace two of the new files with the ones in a specific branch.

I know that I can do that with checkout but...

What is the difference between

```
git checkout wanted_branch file_wanted
```

and

```
git checkout --merge wanted_branch file_wanted
```

?

Comment: So I take it you tried to RTFM but did not understand the famous manual?

Comment: I read the manual, but I wanted to check if I was missing something and the --merge was really important in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the form that you are mentioning, there is really no difference between the two and the `--merge` is superfluous.

`--merge` option is mainly used when you are switching branches and you have local modifications in your working directory, so that rather than just saying you cannot switch branches, you can make git to attempt to do a three-way merge on the modifications and present you with checked out branch with or without the conflicts.

Also, when you do `git checkout --merge -- file` during conflict, you get back the conflicted merge in `file` ( from the index)

The above two are the uses for `--merge` and in the form you mentioned, it is not different from `git checkout some_branch -- file`